# PHP/Symfony - Parsing object properties from Request

Tags: symfony, parsing, request, entity

We're building a REST API in Symfony and in many Controllers we're repeating the same code for parsing and settings properties of objects/entities such as this:

```
$title = $request->request->get('title');

if (isset($title)) {
    $titleObj = $solution->getTitle();
    $titleObj->setTranslation($language, $title);
    $solution->setTitle($titleObj);
}
```

I'm aware that Symfony forms provide this functionality, however, we've decided in the company that we want to move away from Symfony forms and want to use something simplier and more customisable instead.

Could anybody please provide any ideas or examples of libraries that might achieve property parsing and settings to an object/entity? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a good use case for [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html). Basically it allows you, by using `@ParamConverter` annotation to convert params which are coming into your controller into anything you want, so you might just create `ParamConverter` with code which is repeated in many controllers and have it in one place. Then, when using `ParamConverter` your controller will receive your entity/object as a parameter.

```
class ExampleParamConverter implements ParamConverterInterface
{

    public function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
        //put any code you want here
        $title = $request->request->get('title');
        if (isset($title)) {
            $titleObj = $solution->getTitle();
            $titleObj->setTranslation($language, $title);
            $solution->setTitle($titleObj);
        }

        //now you are setting object which will be injected into controller action
        $request->attributes->set($configuration->getName(), $solution);

        return true;
    }

    public function supports(ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in controller:

```
/**
 * @ParamConverter("exampleParamConverter", converter="your_converter")
 */
public function action(Entity $entity)
{
    //you have your object available
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have noticed ParamConverter during my research and I think it could really simplify things, however, it doesn't solve the initial problem, which is mainly automating the parsing itself. In this case, I'd like to call a library which would automatically do the parsing in "apply" method in the ExampleParamConvertor.

Comment: so what do you mean by "parsing" exactly? What it's supposed to do?

Comment: Something like this interface here. It would allow to define what properties will be passed from the Request and automatically set them into the property which could then be validated. https://www.dropbox.com/s/jf5jaqrqxn8r1rx/Screenshot%202016-12-07%2011.47.56.png?dl=0